# How to write a wrapper function for FindOptions in go mongo-driver

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query, driver, golang-migrate

I want to write a wrapper function for [FindOptions](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.10.3/mongo/options#FindOptions) in my dbobject code so that I can avoid importing package `options` in my service code .  Basically i'm trying to accomodate three func under one interface

```
SetSkip() 
SetLimit()
SetSort()
```

so that i should be able to do something like Find().SetSkip().SetLimit() in a single line , is that doable ?

Also I want to know the usage of [MergeFindOptions](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.10.3/mongo/options#MergeFindOptions)

```
func MergeFindOptions(opts ...*FindOptions) *FindOptions
```

Any examples will be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just embed the `options.FindOptions` struct into a custom one. Additionally you could add a `FindOptions` function to initialize this custom struct, like the mongo package do by `options.Find()`.

```golang
package your_db_package

type YourFindOptions struct {
    *options.FindOptions
}

func FindOptions() YourFindOptions {
    return YourFindOptions{options.Find()}
}

// ---
package your_service_package

import "your_db_package"

func GetItems() {
  opts := your_db_package.FindOptions().SetSkip(123).SetLimit(456)
}
```

As the name `MergeFindOptions` and the documentation says it's for merging multiple FindOptions into a new one:

> MergeFindOptions combines the given FindOptions instances into a single FindOptions in a last-one-wins fashion.

Comment: I tried the way you suggested but that did not work . It was not accepting it in a single line and gives me a nil pointer when I tried to run the code . 

`panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x18 pc=0x561becb9e9b4]

goroutine 1 [running]:`

Comment: @Karthik I've put the code into a [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/OyIu2wzd4zD).    
Work's for me. Did you initialize the "FindOptions" correctly?